# I have a numpy array with the shape of 480x600, numpy complex numbers, there is a way to append it in a empty array which has more of these inside?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, complex-numbers

Ok, so in this loop in a function of a class

```
for oo in range(norient):
  ...
  for ss in range(nscale):
    filt=logGabor[ss]*spread
```

This **filt** numpy array contains numpy complex numbers.

So this filt numpy array has a shape of 480x600 and it would do it like 12 times, so I would like to have a numpy array with 12 values which contains the other arrays of 480x600.

In the **init** of the class I started a

`self.espacial=np.empty(shape=(0,12),dtype=complex)`

and in the end of the for I tried to append it, I read that numpy append doesn't work very well in a loop and gave me.

`self.espacial=np.append(self.espacial,filt)`

`ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"`

Comment: If you really want to understand what `np.append` did or did not do, you need to show the actual code and full error message.  Without `axis` it flattens the inputs.  With `axis` it does `np.concatenate`, and expects matching dimensions.  A (0,12) can't be joined to a (480.600) on any axis.  12 (480,600) arrays can be joined on a new axis to make (12,480,600), or on any of the shared dimensions, e.g. (12*480,600).

Answer (score 1):

Numpy arrays aren't very good if the size constantly changes, instead collect into a list and convert to an array at the end:

```py
special = []
for oo in range(norient):
    …
    for ss in range(nscale):
        filt=logGabor[ss]*spread
        special.append(filt)

special = np.array(special)
```

Comment: I tried to do that but the thing is the values of **filt** are numpy complex numbers so I get this error 
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Note that I don't initally make special a `np.array`